# Configure apache mod_ssl to use different certificates for incoming and outgoing messages

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, mod-ssl

How could I configure `mod_ssl` to use different certificates for incoming and outgoing messages? I have managed to configure `apache2` only to handle incoming messages with single certificate. Is it possible to separate incoming and outgoing flows? How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use SSL/TLS, the server certificate is only used to authenticate the server. Shared keys are negotiated during the handshake, with different keys for client write and server write operations (see [*Key Calculation*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346#section-6.3) for the details).

If you're talking about "outgoing messages" in terms of Apache Httpd behaving as a reverse proxy (and thus being a client to another server), you can use the `SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile` configuration directive to use a client certificate if needed.